# Layout - Constraints wont work

Tags: android, layout, constraints

Hope you guys can help me, I created an xml layout but constraint would not work, when I run my app it gives me an error. Ive clicked on the Infer Constraints and it still wont work. Any Suggestions? Ive attached a picture and xml coding.

[Layout Constraints Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngT6q.jpg)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewAddCalendar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Calendar"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="115dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<!-- Spinner Dropdown -->
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/SpinnerAddress"
    android:layout_width="201dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="168dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewAddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Address: "
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCheckInDate"
    android:layout_width="146dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:text="Check In Date:"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="118dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtCheckInDate"
    android:layout_width="223dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="171dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="118dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCheckOutDate"
    android:layout_width="147dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:text="Check Out Date:"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="177dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtCheckOutDate"
    android:layout_width="223dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="171dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="177dp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rdGrpPoolHeat"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="262dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnPoolHeatYes"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnPoolHeatNo"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:text="No"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RadioGroup>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewPoolHeat"
    android:layout_width="91dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:text="POOL HEAT:"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="237dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewGrill"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="Grill:"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="217dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="235dp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rdGrpGrill"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="217dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="255dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnGrillYes"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnGrillNo"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:text="No"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RadioGroup>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewCrib"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:text="CRIB:"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="364dp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rdGrpCrib"
    android:layout_width="147dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="373dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnCribYes"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnCribNo"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:text="No"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewHighChair"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="HIGH CHAIR:"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="214dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="351dp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rdGrpHighChair"
    android:layout_width="147dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="222dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="373dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnHighChairYes"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnHighChairNo"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:text="No"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewRollAwayBed"
    android:layout_width="103dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:text="Roll Away Bed:"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="470dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtRollAwayBed"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="0"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="115dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="467dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewComments"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Comments:"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="505dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtComments"
    android:layout_width="387dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="524dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddCalendar"
    android:layout_width="129dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Calendar"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="68dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="593dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
    android:layout_width="129dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="209dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="593dp" />
```

I have been trying for almost a day and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which/What error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I deleted the layout editor absolute x and y and replaced it with the constraints

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewAddCalendar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Add Calendar"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewAddress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:text="Address: "
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.047"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<!-- Spinner Dropdown -->
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/SpinnerAddress"
    android:layout_width="201dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.473"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCheckInDate"
    android:layout_width="146dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:text="Check In Date:"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtCheckInDate"
    android:layout_width="223dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCheckOutDate"
    android:layout_width="147dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="212dp"
    android:text="Check Out Date:"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtCheckOutDate"
    android:layout_width="223dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="212dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rdGrpPoolHeat"
    android:layout_width="154dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="332dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.056"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnPoolHeatYes"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnPoolHeatNo"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:text="No"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RadioGroup>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewPoolHeat"
    android:layout_width="91dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="308dp"
    android:text="POOL HEAT:"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.049"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewGrill"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="312dp"
    android:text="Grill:"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.559"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rdGrpGrill"
    android:layout_width="157dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="332dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.702"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnGrillYes"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnGrillNo"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:text="No"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RadioGroup>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewCrib"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="432dp"
    android:text="CRIB:"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.045"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rdGrpCrib"
    android:layout_width="147dp"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="456dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnCribYes"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnCribNo"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:text="No"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewHighChair"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="428dp"
    android:text="HIGH CHAIR:"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.596"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rdGrpHighChair"
    android:layout_width="152dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="452dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.697"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnHighChairYes"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rdbtnHighChairNo"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:text="No"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewRollAwayBed"
    android:layout_width="103dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="560dp"
    android:text="Roll Away Bed:"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtRollAwayBed"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="552dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="0"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.234"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewComments"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="624dp"
    android:text="Comments:"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.054"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtComments"
    android:layout_width="421dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="624dp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.577"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddCalendar"
    android:layout_width="186dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="103dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="103dp"
    android:text="Add Calendar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtViewHighChair"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtViewComments" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="776dp"
    android:text="Cancel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.758"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

That fixed my issue and works well now.